# How to get a clip's source media starting and ending frame numbers?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've used the Blender VSE (2.77a) to edit 7 original source media files which are each about 20 mins in length.  I have been unable to get a usable render of the edited video project out of Blender so I need to transition the project to plan B.

My backup plan is to use a different piece of software to recut the original source media using my blender clips as a reference.

Ideally, Blender could spit out an Edit Decision List (EDL) sequential list of every clip in sequencer that looked like this:

'#'; SourceMediaFileName; VseStartFrame; VseEndFrame; SourceMediaStartFrame; SourceMediaEndFrame

I can't find any feature for this type of export in Blender so my other option would be to manually build this list.  My problem is that I'm having trouble locating the SourceMediaStartFrame and SourceMediaEndFrame (those are just random aliases) values.

When I select one of the clips in the Sequencer, the Edit Strip window shows the following relevant data:
Start Frame
Length
Final Length
Playhead
Frame Offset

Each of the original source media was about 77000 frames.  So what pieces of the Edit Strip data would tell me the start frame and end frame from the original source media for each clip?

If it can't be found here, where else would I look?  Is there any easier way to build an EDL of all of the clips in my Sequencer and their start/end frames in relation to the source media?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

-Caleb

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that prints strip details to the system console.  Note how the python property names are shown when you mouse over the field in the Properties Panel of the VSE. If this answer is heading in the right direction, give me a heads up and can edit to format the output more specifically to suit your needs.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
vse = scene.sequence_editor

for strip in vse.sequences_all:
    # Edit Strip Panel
    print("-" * 72)
    print(strip.name)
    print(strip.type)
    # extend for other strip types.
    if strip.type in ['MOVIE']:
        print(strip.filepath)
    elif strip.type in ['SOUND']:
        print(strip.sound.filepath)
    print(strip.channel)
    print(strip.frame_start)
    print(strip.frame_final_duration)
    # Trim Duration (soft)
    print(strip.frame_offset_start)
    print(strip.frame_offset_end)
```