# Pull clip info from crossfades/fades via python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, video-sequence-editor, video

How do I pull information on what clips affected by crossfades/transitions and fades via python?

I know I can pull the type of clip with this script, but not the affected clips of crossfades and fades: [How to get a clip's source media starting and ending frame numbers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53330/how-to-get-a-clips-source-media-starting-and-ending-frame-numbers)

(I'm trying to piece together an EDL export script: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?418606-EDL-export-script-help-needed!
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hover over an Effect strips Input boxes and get the Python variable:

[image: CrossSequence.input]

So you just need to call `.input_1` on the effect strip to access the first effected strip. Then you can access its attributes like normal (e.g. `.filepath`) as it's just a reference to the original strip.

The best help is your autocompletion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) in an interactive Python console view. So just write the complete `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all['Cross'].input_1` into one and hit the <kbd>.</kbd> (dot), then call the autocompletion and it will print you any possible accessible attributes of this strip.