# Get start and end frame of multiple strips?

Tags: animation, scripting, actions

I'm working on a platform that requires me to introduce Frame start and end of my animation strips.

I've been looking for a scrip to get a **list of the frame range** of all the strips i have on my NLA.

I foun this in [another thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53330/how-to-get-a-clips-source-media-starting-and-ending-frame-numbers/53364#53364) but it only works for media sources. I hope somebody can help me modify this script to get NLA strip's frame range.

Here's the script i found:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
vse = scene.sequence_editor

for strip in vse.sequences_all:
    # Edit Strip Panel
    print("-" * 72)
    print(strip.name)
    print(strip.type)
    # extend for other strip types.
    if strip.type in ['MOVIE']:
        print(strip.filepath)
    elif strip.type in ['SOUND']:
        print(strip.sound.filepath)
    print(strip.channel)
    print(strip.frame_start)
    print(strip.frame_final_duration)
    # Trim Duration (soft)
    print(strip.frame_offset_start)
    print(strip.frame_offset_end)
```

Comment: NLA strips don't show up in the vse, but are data attached to the object.  You need to iterate through objects to find their animation_data, and if they have any, then the nla_tracks associated with that and the strips associated with each track.  I'm off to dinner, but I'll write up an example later if nobody else already has.

Answer (score 4):

**Look up the docs, use the python console.**

With developer extras on, if we right click on any field and select "Online Python Reference" on for example NLA strip frame start it opens docs for  [`NLAStrip.frame_start`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.91/bpy.types.NlaStrip.html#bpy.types.NlaStrip.frame_start)

[image]

Small script, loop over all objects in scene, then any or all of their NLA data, print name of object, track and strip. Print frame start and frame end of each strip

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for ob in context.scene.objects:
    if not ob.animation_data:
        continue
    print(ob.name)
    for track in ob.animation_data.nla_tracks:
        print("  ", track.name)
        for strip in track.strips:
            print(" " * 4, strip.name, strip.frame_start, strip.frame_end)
```

Result for IMG above.

```
Cube
   NlaTrack.002
     CubeAction.003 3.0 67.0
   NlaTrack.001
     CubeAction.002 155.0 219.0
   NlaTrack
     CubeAction -0.29999998211860657 63.79999923706055
     CubeAction.001 110.39999389648438 145.0
```

**Using the python console.**

Now we know roundabouts where things are, can make tests in python console, for example the strips of bottom track

```
>>> strips = C.object.animation_data.nla_tracks[0].strips
```

Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> auto completes with available options

```
>>> strips['CubeAction.003'].
                             action
                             action_frame_end
                             action_frame_start
                             active
```

for example from above [NLAStrip.action_frame_end](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.91/bpy.types.NlaStrip.html#bpy.types.NlaStrip.action_frame_end)

**References.**

Further to the docs, if you scroll down to the bottom to references

[image]

it will show ways to reference an instance of that object, in this case an NLA strip.
In code above have iterated  `NLATrack.strips` collection. (via `track.strips`)

If in context of NLA editor, to run over all selected strips, much like context selected objects,  use

```
for strip in context.selected_nla_strips:
    blah
```

Notice too that a strip has a strips collection, which reminded me, if the strip is a META strip, could check for that, *eg*

```
        if strip.type == 'META':
            for s in strip.strips:
                print(s.name)
```

Comment: This does not find CubeAction in a simple animation of a cube moving on the Y axis.